# getting a FileNotFoundException error that we have not covered in class yet

Tags: java, iterator

im trying to make a class that will read in text from  a file and put it into an array, and im coming across an error that we have not covered in class yet...

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Card
   {
   File inputFile = new File("Cards.txt");
   Scanner textScan = new Scanner(inputFile);
   {
   String[] cards = new String[51];

   for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
      {
      while (textScan.hasNextLine())
         cards[i] = textScan.nextLine();
      }
   }
}
```

and this is the error:

```
Card.java:7: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
   Scanner textScan = new Scanner(inputFile);
                      ^
1 error
```

thanks in advance, also im pretty new to java as you can probably tell from what im working on, so if you could dumb down your responses as much as possible that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Google `must be caught or declared to be thrown`.

Comment: file location is not correct. Give the full path of the file

Answer (score 0):

[Constructor of `Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) declares to throw `FileNotFoundException` so it must be handled (either by catching or by rethrowing)

Answer (score 0):

You must catch the exception using a Try-Catch statement like this

```
try{
    Scanner textScan = new Scanner(inputFile);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

It's like telling Java what to do if you can't find the file 'inputFile' is referenced to.